# BrowserQuest on Debian

Tags: node.js, html, debian, server

I want to install BrowserQuest on our Debian server but everytime when I try to start the Server the following error appears:

> throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
>                     ^
>   Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
>   at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:15)
>   at Function._load (module.js:281:25)
>   at Module.require (module.js:358:17)
>   at require (module.js:374:17)
>   at Object. (/root/BrowserQuest/server/js/metrics.js:3:9)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:445:26)
>   at Object..js (module.js:463:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:352:32)
>   at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
>   at Module.require (module.js:358:17)
>
> node 0.7.6 is installed
>   npm 1.1.8 is installed
>   Debian 8.0

THe BrowserQuest Folder is under `/root/BrowserQuest`

Thanks

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Answer (score 0):

The "throw e" message does not reveal the real problem.
What really matters should be, I guess, the following messages like "cannot find package underscore", "cannot find package websocket-server", etc.
The fact is that you should do "npm install -d " for all those packages.

However the official repository has been out-of-date, so you have to replace websocket-server by node-websocket-server, and some other minor fixes in javascript sources.